# Imported type defined multiple times on Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

Here are my imports:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;    
using Android.Support.V4.View;
```

Then

```
var mPager = FindViewById<ViewPager> (Resource.Id.pager);
```

This line gives me **The imported type 'Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager' is defined multiple times**

what is wrong in here?

ps: both v4 and v13 are referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include V4 and V13. V13 is a superset of V4 and includes V4 in it. So that's why you're getting multiple definitions. Remove the V4 reference and it should work fine.

Comment: I had the same issue trying to upgrade an application from supporting API level 19 to 23. I only had the V4 support library imported as a package and still got that duplicate definitions error. I removed the v4 library all together and the error went away. What is very odd is I am still referencing Xamarin.Support.V4 in my project and it works. has the latest versions of Xamarin.Android automatically imported these frameworks under the covers?