# Imported type defined multiple times on Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm getting the following error in my Xamarin.Android project:

> The imported type Android.Support.v4.view.ViewPager is defined multiple times

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496549/imported-type-defined-multiple-times-on-xamarin-android) solution, but doesn not work. In fact I need to use the Google Play Store binding library and it uses both support v4 and v7. If I try to remove the v4 I get an error like this:

> Unable to uninstall 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 20.0.0.4' because 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices 19.0.0.1' depends on it.

[image]

ps: I'm using `Facebook Android SDK` and `Crittercism` components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only working solution I found is the following:

- remove the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices package (and its dependencies)
- remove the Facebook component
- install the Facebook component **first**
- then install again the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices package

I don't know why this process is required, but it works